# How to copy data from flex table

Tags: vertica, flextable

I have a huge CSV file that I loaded into Flex Table, the csv contains more columns than required.
now I would like to copy the data from the flex table to my regular table (include mapping columns ) .
I tried "insert select" but I got some error regarding casting , so I tried to run insert ignore which is not supported in Vertica.
in my case I don't care to lost messages.
I thought about write copy with rejected table but I can't find what is the right syntax.
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the COPY command you use to load into flex table, and some sample data from your csv.

Comment: create flex table flex_table();
copy public.flex_table from '/data/csv/data_june7_15.csv'  PARSER fcsvparser();
regarding the data:
i have about 100 columns in the csv,  most of tham are float, some are timestampa and some Strings.
my Vertica table contains about 60 columns.

I also created a view :
select compute_flextable_keys_and_build_view('flex_table');

Now i would like to copy the data from the view table into a regular table.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to [materialize](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/FlexTables/MaterializingFlexTables.htm) the columns you want in the flex table. So when you run the `COPY` command only values that match the correct data types will be loaded.

Assuming your data looks like:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col4
1.2,2019-07-01 10:00:00,1,string 2
1.2,2019-07-01 10:00:00,string 1,string 2
```

And you only care about col1, col2, col3. Where col3 contains mixed int and string values.

Create the flex table and load the csv:

```
CREATE FLEX TABLE flex_table
(
    col1 float,
    col2 timestamp, 
    col3 int
);

COPY public.flex_table FROM '/data/csv/data_june7_15.csv' PARSER fcsvparser();
```

Then, you can insert the data into your regular table from your flex table (no need for the view):

```
CREATE TABLE regular_table
(
    col1 float,
    col2 timestamp,
    col3 int
);

INSERT INTO regular_table (col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM flex_table;

SELECT * FROM regular_table;
 col1 |        col2         | col3 
------+---------------------+------
  1.2 | 2019-07-01 10:00:00 |     
  1.2 | 2019-07-01 10:00:00 |    1
```